# Best way to detect Text selection change on UWP WebView control

Tags: webview, uwp

I am using  a WebView control to show some html pages and now i have to support text selection feature on this 
browser control. I am plannig to show some ActionMenus to user once he select some text

- User hit on control and start text selection by dragging
- User doubleclick on a text  and select the text
- If its a touch device user do tap event and might select the text

  So how can i raise the event to show the Menus to end user

  KeyDown

  KeyUp

  DragEnter

  DragLeave

  DoubleTapped

DO i need to use all these events to make it work on both keyboard/mouse interaction & touch interaction

Answer (score 0):

WebView does not natively support the events that you have specified.
Refer : [WebView Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) - **Events** section.

Also read the **Remarks** section to find a workaround for your problem.

Quick read from documentation : WebView doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as **KeyDown**, **KeyUp**, and **PointerPressed**. A common workaround is to use *InvokeScriptAsync* with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use *window.external.notify* from the HTML event handler to notify the application using *WebView.ScriptNotify*.

Comment: Any useful resources available for doing this? My intention is to allow the user to process the selected content from web view

Comment: I think [this](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsofts-edge-team-encouraging-developers-build-browsers) will help you the most.
The source code is available on [git hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser)

Comment: I read msdn description remarks section and what i understood is the keyboard events will work only when they have input focus. This means if webview have focus then i can use the above events right?